# Way to detect angle (0, 90, -90, 180) of the phone in JS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I am using JavaScript. I need to know when user changed the orientation of the phone and I also need to know to which orientation ( 0, 90, -90 or 180).

- I tried to use `orientationchange` from the docs.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
  console.log("the orientation of the device is now " + event.target.screen.orientation.angle);
});
```

Unfortunatelly, This doesn't work on IOS Safari. There's no `orientation` object in `event.target.screen`.

- I tried using `window.orientation` (seems like it's working, but from the docs, it's deprecated and MUST be avoided.
- I tried `resize` listener .

```
window.onresize =  () => {
    if(window.innerWidth >= window.innerHeight){
          //landscape
     }
    else{
        //portrait
    }
};
```

This has 2 problems. 1) Sometimes this doesn't detect correctly on some iPhones or maybe on the same iPhone, but at different times. 2) I have no idea how to know the angle.(0,90, -90, 180). I don't know much about screens and `innerHeight` or `innerWidth` or stuff like that.

Any proper solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried beta (for the x-axis) or gamma (for the y-axis)?

e.g.

```
function handleOrientation(event) {
var absolute = event.absolute;
var alpha    = event.alpha; // z-axis
var beta     = event.beta;  // x-axis
var gamma    = event.gamma; // y-axis

// Do stuff with the new orientation data
```

}

Comment: orientationchange event gives me `event`, but there's no absolute or any other properties on that object you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `deviceorientation` event on the window.

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(e){
    const {absolute, alpha, beta, gamma} = e;
});
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation#Orientation_values_explained):

> - The DeviceOrientationEvent.alpha value represents the motion of the device around the z axis, represented in degrees with values ranging from 0 to 360.
> - The DeviceOrientationEvent.beta value represents the motion of the device around the x axis, represented in degrees with values ranging from -180 to 180. This represents a front to back motion of the device.
> - The DeviceOrientationEvent.gamma value represents the motion of the device around the y axis, represented in degrees with values ranging from -90 to 90. This represents a left to right motion of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Problem that I got is even though i accepted permission from orientation change event , by using ` DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()`, It still doesn't call `deviceorientation` event. Could it be because I am testing this locally(on self signed certificate ? ) or it won't work on safari ios simulator ?